# Difference between persistent and non-persistent delivery

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I read following [ActiveMQ FAQ](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-difference-between-persistent-and-non-persistent-delivery.html) and my understanding from this is that suppose I am sending a message to my ActiveMQ server while ActiveMQ server is down, but if I have marked my producer's delivery mode as persistent `producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);` then message will be delivered once the ActiveMQ server is up.

Now, to test this I simply stopped my ActiveMQ server and then sent a message from a JMS producer, now as expected I got connection refused error (please note that I didn't close my JMS producer connection/borker) but I when I started my ActiveMQ server then I didn't get that message.

Did I misunderstood that FAQ, if yes then what does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send a message persistent the broker stores that message in a store on disk to be recovered later should the broker go down or is shutdown and later restarted.  When a message is sent as non-persistent it is stored only in memory and should the broker stop for some reason those messages are lost, never to be heard from again.

When the broker is down and you try and send to it, then as you might imagine the broker can't store the messages that were sent persistently as it was....down.

If the client uses a failover transport than the send should block waiting for a reconnection to occur either to the same broker or an alternate that you've configured and will then send the message to that broker.  When not using failover transport the client gets and error and it is up to you resend at a later time.

Setting persistent as the send mode does not transcend time and space to make the message arrive at the broker before it went down.

Comment: Perfect, that clarifies my confusion.

Comment: One more clarification please - I see that at my JMS application where I am sending and receiving message I see a directory created like `activemq-data\localhost\KahaDB` and it is certainly used as a message store, I am wondering what is this store used for? I could understand the persistent store like KahaDB getting used by broker but what's the purpose of this at my JMS application end. Along with your answer if you would provide me some link where I can know more about it then it would really be helpful.

Comment: @hagrawal please post this as a new question rather than a comment

Comment: @Tim: Will you be able to answer from comment or should I open a new question?

Comment: Need to ask a new question and properly explain what you are doing and what the issue is.